# Error: cout does not type a name

Tags: c++

Paso parámetros por referencia pero recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> cout does not type a name

¿Por qué puede ocurrir eso? Éste es mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
void valornuevo(int&,int&);      // Paso de parametros por referencia
                                 // leccion 68     Problema con el cout
int main(){
    int num1,num2;

    cout<<"digite dos numeros :";
    cin>>num1>>num2;
    valornuevo(num1,num2);

    getch();
    return 0;   
 }

 void valornuevo(int& numx,int& numy);
     cout<<"el valor del primero numero es:"<<numx<<endl;   
     cout<<"el valor del segundo numero es:"<<numy<<endl;
     void valornuevo(int& numx,int& numy);
     cout<<"el valor del primer numero es: "<<numx<<endl;
     cout<<"el valor del segundo numero es: "<<numy<<endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Cambia esto:

```
void valornuevo(int& numx,int& numy);
cout<<"el valor del primero numero es:"<<numx<<endl;   
cout<<"el valor del segundo numero es:"<<numy<<endl;
```

por esto:

```
void valornuevo(int& numx,int& numy){
cout<<"el valor del primero numero es:"<<numx<<endl;   
cout<<"el valor del segundo numero es:"<<numy<<endl;
}
```

El punto y coma luego de la función indica que ese es el final de la sentencia.

Comment: Eso y eliminar una de las dos funciones, ya que no puedes tener dos funciones con el mismo nombre y el mismo tipo de argumentos... esta respuesta tal y como está se antoja incompleta